# div scroll with padding?

Tags: html, text, scroll, padding

I am new to html / css and am still learning a few things, currently I am trying to create a simple chat style box as can be seen here:

http://jsfiddle.net/29n3w/

Is there a way to rework this code so that the text inside the div respects the padding and is cut off 9px from the border of the top and bottom instead of getting cut off at the well's border? I'd also like to keep the scrollbar the way it is now.

I've searched for a while but cannot seem to devise a solution to this.

Ideally this is what I am aiming for: http://img839.imageshack.us/img839/3889/examplejt.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to wrap the text in another div and make the new div scrollable. then you put padding to your `well`..check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/kdaker/La9Jn/7/

Comment: i dont know about that really... you might be able to achieve it with a different effect .. [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6545947/442328) could help. Instead of using paddings though you could use small image 'strips' that have same color as the `well` background. not sure if that would work though.

Comment: This answer adds 3 vertical scrollbars. The padding on the elements make the others to create a new scrollbar, and nothing I can do can fix it. Even the body has a scrollbar!, and the first element inside is fixed to less than half the available body height!
It seems calculations around/inside scrollbars only take actual content or fixed width/heights without paddings or margins. Totally dissapointing from Chrome 43.0 Mac