# How to have a scrollbar on body for scrolling content within a centered, middled div?

Tags: javascript, css, layout, position, scrollbar

I need a fixed-height, fixed-width div centered (horizontally) and middled (vertically) on the viewport. There'll be a navigation bar which must be 'fixed' to the top of that div. I have content which overflows and requires a scrollbar. However, instead of the scrollbar on the div, I want it to resemble a more traditional scrollbar - on the right most position of the browser.

A close solution came from a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6545894/2317532), however [their solution](http://jsfiddle.net/tcaVN/1/) does not keep the content div fixed-height/width.

Here's [what I have now](http://jsfiddle.net/dTZpr/1/). I would prefer a purely-CSS solution, but I understand Javascript might be necessary.

**HTML**

```
<div class="verMidOut">
    <div class="verMidMid">
        <div class="verMidIn">
            <div class="scroller">
                <div id="headerContainer" style="visibility: visible;">
                    <p>This (navigation bar) has to stay 'fixed' to the top of the red box</p>
                </div>
                <div class="mainContainer index">
                    <p>ee</p><p>ee</p><p>ee</p><p>ee</p><p>ee</p><p>ee</p><p>ee</p><p>ee</p><p>ee</p><p>ee</p><p>ee</p><p>ee</p><p>ee</p><p>ee</p><p>ee</p><p>ee</p><p>ee</p><p>ee</p><p>ee</p><p>ee</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;overflow-x:hidden}
.verMidOut {width:100%; height:100%; display:table; position:relative; border: 4px solid blue; overflow: hidden;}
.verMidMid {width:100%; display:table-cell; top:50%; vertical-align:middle; *position:absolute; border: 4px solid green; background-position: center;}
.verMidIn {width:100%; position:relative; top:-50%; border: 4px solid red;}
.mainContainer {border: 5px solid black;margin: auto;width: 512px;height: 325px;}
.scroller {width: 100%;overflow: auto;overflow-x:hidden;}
#headerContainer{visibility: hidden; margin-left:-256px;width:512px;height:80px;left:50%;position:absolute;top:15px;z-index:10;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An early solution I had can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/XR7kQ/2/), which uses jQuery, however, the scrollbar only appears when the content overflows the body, and not the content div (black/red in the jsFiddle).

Then I [added a spacer](http://jsfiddle.net/XR7kQ/3/) in the content div which dynamically changes its height depending on the window height and div height. This forces the scrollbar to appear even though there's nothing there.

**HTML**

```
<div class="verMidOut">
    <div class="verMidMid">
        <div id="headerContainer" style="visibility: visible;">
            <p>This (navigation bar) has to stay 'fixed' to the top of the red box</p>
        </div>
        <div class="verMidIn">
            <div class="mainContainer index">
                <p>ee</p><p>ee</p><p>ee</p><p>ee</p><p>ee</p><p>ee</p><p>ee</p><p>ee</p>
                <div class="spacer"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;overflow-x:hidden}
.verMidOut {width:100%; height:100%; display:table; position:relative; border: 4px solid blue; overflow: hidden;}
.verMidMid {width:100%; display:table-cell; top:50%; vertical-align:middle; *position:absolute; border: 4px solid green; background-position: center;overflow:hidden;overflow-y:auto;}
.verMidIn {width:100%; position:relative; top:-50%; border: 4px solid red;}
.mainContainer {border: 5px solid black;margin: auto;width: 512px;height: 325px;}
#headerContainer{visibility: hidden; margin-left:-256px;width:512px;height:80px;left:50%;position:absolute;top:15px;z-index:10;}
.spacer {display:inline-block;visibility:hidden;}
```

**jQuery**

```
//When the window is more than the height of the black box, it will calculate the 'top' for the headerContainer
function posNav() {
    if($(window).height() > $('.mainContainer').height()) {
        var diff = (($(window).height() - $('.mainContainer').height()) / 2);
        var newTop = diff + 15;
        $('.spacer').css({'height': diff});
        $('#headerContainer').css({'top': newTop});
    }
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    posNav();
    $(window).resize(function(){
        posNav();
    });
});
```